# Plot data entry trends of grouped data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple task of grouping my data by Brand and plotting data entry trends however when I try this it doesnt work as expected and my x-axis also doesnt show periodic dates of data entry using plotly express plotting.

Here is my code and what I tried

```
import pandas as pd

cars2 = {'Date': ['2021-04-11','2021-04-12','2021-04-13','2021-04-14', '2021-04-15'],
        'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4','Mercedes'],
        'Price': [22000,5000,27000,35000,45000],
        'Mileage': [2000,100,47000,3500,600]
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(cars2, columns = ['Date','Brand', 'Price', 'Mileage'])

print (df2)

df3 = df2.groupby(['Brand'])['Date'].value_counts()


import plotly.express as px
data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
fig = px.bar(df3, x='Date', y='Date')
fig.show()
```

My expected output is grouping this data by Brand then plot using dates to find data entry trends for the given period.I also dont understand why x-axis is not showing the dates required. Any assistance will be apppreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2.groupby(['Brand'])['Date'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do want x-axis to have dates instand of brands

Comment: Then you need `df2.groupby(['Date'])['Brand'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar()`